# Sci-fi movie that remember watching as a child involving a beetle-like creature escaping a space prison to Earth, and then going back

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, b-movies

I believe the main plot of the movie involved an alien escaping from some space prison and coming to Earth. The two protagonists was a man and a woman and I believe one of them was a cop. In one of the scenes I remember a beetle like creature coming out of the mouth of a scientist, and another scene I remember the alien making it back up to the space prison where it took over the minds of all the prisoners and there seemed to be some  large prison orgy of some sort with a giant beetle in the center of it. They finally defeated the creature by crashing the spaceship into the ocean.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  What year would this have been?  What language?  If you saw it on TV, any idea what channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly 1988's *[Something is Out There](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_Is_Out_There)*? Joe Cortese played a cop and the alien escaped from a space prison. Maryam D'Abo played the female helping hunt the alien.

> Jack Breslin (Joseph Cortese) is a police officer investigating brutal murders in which organs have been removed from the victims. He learns that the crimes are being committed by a monstrous alien insectoid prisoner known as a xenomorph, possessing shape-shifting and physical possession abilities, who has escaped from an alien prison starship passing by the solar system, and he teams up with a beautiful medical officer from that ship, Ta'Ra (Maryam d'Abo), to track down the villain. Ta'Ra has assorted superhuman abilities, including telepathy and superhuman agility, which come in handy during the mission.

### Trailer

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your help, it's been driving me crazy trying to figure out the title so I could try and rewatch it.